GA4 custom event has not been triggered consistently
We have used custom event to send data to GA4 and we configured GA4 to BigQuery data link. We have found two problems:
-Events are shown with the same event_timestamp in spite of they have actually happened in user's web browser in different time. For the example in the attached screenshot,  sunmit_claims_starts and nbaDashboardInit have the same event timestamp, but they were fired in browser in different time.

-There are sessions that are not sending all the events from GA4 to BQ. for example user_logs_in_session has not been sent to BQ consisently.
